# Can't connect using Prisma to Postgresql container running in Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to run Postgresql inside Docker, and connect to it via Prisma. I've looked at multiple issues and I can't see anything wrong with what I'm trying to do.

I can't seem to ping my postgresql instance either, or connect to adminer.

Most common issue people had was with using `localhost` instead of the docker image name.

I've also tried disabling firewalld, but that made no difference so I do not think it's my firewall blocking the port either.

Thanks!

.env

```
DB_NAME=spot
DB_HOST=postgres
DB_USERNAME=spotuser
DB_PASSWORD=spotpass
DB_PORT=5432

DATABASE_URL=`postgresql://${DB_USERNAME}:${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}?schema=public`
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

```
❯ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE      COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
e66b70a9ac69   adminer    "entrypoint.sh docke…"   6 minutes ago   Up 2 seconds   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   spot-spot-adminer-1
dd629496a246   postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 minutes ago   Up 2 seconds   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   spot-spot-postgres-1
```

Comment: Where Prima running?  How did you try to ping postgresql (from where, and what was the full command you ran, and what was the result?).  How did you try to connect to adminer (again, from where, and what was the full command you ran, and what was the result?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was me! I usually have a VPN running so I didn't think about it. As soon as I disabled it, everything worked as expected.

I did however have to use `localhost` instead of `postgresql` as my `DB_HOST`. (I had tried this initially but no luck, that's when I came across a few SO answers that said you need to use container name rather than localhost).

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#expose

Try adding expose to your `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    expose:
      - 5432
```